# Keep an element scrolled to the bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a "log" screen that updates periodically in React. To make sure that the latest addition is always in view I would like the element to always be scrolled to the bottom:

[image: Example of what I want to acheive]

I have the overflow working:

## CSS:

```
div.log {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And the HTML:

## JSX:

```
render() {

    return (

            <div className="log">
                <ul>
                    {this.props.log.map((log, i) =>

                        <li key={i}>
                            {log.message}
                        </li>
                    )}

                </ul>
            </div>

    );
}
```

Here is my entire component:

## Javascript

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Log extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

    }

    render() {

        return (

                <div className="log">
                    <ul>
                        {this.props.log.map((log, i) =>

                            <li key={i}>
                                {log.message}
                            </li>
                        )}

                    </ul>
                </div>

        );
    }

}
```

This all works fine, but doesn't stay scrolled down. I understand that I can use something similar to:

```
 var element = document.getElementByClassName(".log");
 element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
```

But this only works once, I need to be scrolled to the bottom when the contents of ".log" updates.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could make it as a callback, so everytime you execute the function to get log updates, you can add that to the end of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a `ref` to the topmost element of the `Log` component and make sure it is scrolled to the bottom when the props update in `componentDidUpdate`.

**Example**

```js
class Log extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.ref.current.scrollTop = this.ref.current.scrollHeight;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.ref} style={{ height: 50, overflowY: "scroll" }}>
        <ul>
          {this.props.log.map((log, i) => (
            <li key={i}>{log.message}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { logs: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { logs: [...prevState.logs, { message: Math.random() }] };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <Log log={this.state.logs} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Works great thank you. I had to update my `react` and `react-dom` to > `16.3` so I could use `createRef()`.